# Eclipse isn't overwriting parenthesis

Tags: java, python, eclipse, pydev

This isn't really a coding problem, but more of just an Eclipse problem.

Say you're typing x = (1), Eclipse will make the closing parenthesis for you the moment you type '('
It also normally writes over the closing parenthesis as you are typing as well.

However, for some reason when I'm typing, it doesn't automatically write over it and I'm confused because I'm pretty sure I didn't hit any special setting so I have no idea what to do to revert this.

So normally you'll type x = (1), and it'll show as x = (1), but right now it's showing x(1)). How do I change it back??

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is `x` a method or constructor?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's just an example - just any time of using the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the Settings `Content Assist` for your Editor. It has a setting to overwrite or not. And in my case it specifically mentions you can toggle that with Ctrl Key while the assist is active. The other setting related is `Editor -> Typing`. It also has some brace-close settings.

Comment: Contest assist -> Completion overwrites is only for the completion overwriting (as the name says). This, sadly, does not fix the braces problem.

Answer (score 0):

1 way to solve this problem is by turning off Automatically Closed parentheses. Open the preferences for editing, then go to Java -> Editor -> Typing and turn off parentheses.